# Вставка пробела - PHP

Tags: php, символы

Есть строка:

```
$l_array[] = "<span class='attr'>" . $l['l_n'] . "," . "</span>";
```

Как вставить пробел после запятой не используя `&nbsp`?

Comment: Пробел после `,` не сделать кроме `&nbsp`. Браузеры будут их игнорировать. Можно сделать отступ от правого края.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте пробел после запятой и все. Не нужно там ни каких кодов.

Answer (score 0):

Как то вот так, просто у вас в начале строки не было кавычек и не понятно зачем точку обернули в кавычки двойные:

```
$l_array[] = "<span class='attr'>".$l['l_n'].", .</span>";
```

Если же точку нужно вывести с этими двойными кавычками, нужно их экранировать:

```
$l_array[] = "<span class='attr'>".$l['l_n'].", \".\"</span>";
```

Comment: Нужно без точки просто пробел после запятой.

Comment: @Domilola просто с первого моего варианта точку уберите в конце и всё

Comment: Так не срабатывает

Comment: @Domilola быть не может, что пишет?

Comment: Ничего не пишет, просто после запятой нету пробела.

Comment: `&nbsp;` туда явно впишите и будет вам счастие :)

Comment: @teran он же как раз так и не хочет) но я сомневаюсь что оно не работает) дело в чем то другом

Comment: Может быть проблема в том что в итоге span еще заворачивается в h3?

Comment: @Domilola тут я не подскажу, нужно всю верстку смотреть, но если посмотрите через исходный код - пробел там должен быть

Comment: Да, там есть пробелы.

Comment: @Domilola значит причина в css я так думаю.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan а точно, пропустил этот момент

Answer (score 0):

Откройте для себя функцию `sprintf()`. И Ваш код станет гораздо более читаемым

```
$l_array[] = sprintf("<span class='attr'>%s, </span>", $l['l_n']);
```

Comment: откройте для себя шаблонизаторы, и вообще такого треша писать не придется

Answer (score 0):

Приведите чуть больше текста верстки, чтобы понимать контекст.

Если вам нужен отступ от соседнего блока, то кмк лучше это решить через CSS, а не пробелом.

[CSS: padding](http://htmlbook.ru/css/padding)

[CSS: margin](http://htmlbook.ru/css/margin)